# Menu Drawer not closing smooth as it opens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, slidingdrawer

I am using menu drawer in my android application. It opens smoothly but when it closes the drawer closes first then the layout disappears. till that it shows.

```
 mDrawer = (MenuDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawer.setTouchMode(MenuDrawer.TOUCH_MODE_BEZEL);
```

I call this function on button

```
 public void changeMenuDrawer() {
    mDrawer.setMenuSize(800);
    mDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.contacts_menu_drawer);

    mDrawer.toggleMenu();
}
```

Another function is

```
public void showMenuDrawer() {
    //mDrawer.setMenuSize(700);
    mDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.setting_menu_drawer);
    mDrawer.toggleMenu();
}
```

Comment: Are you seeing these results on an emulator or device?

Comment: on both. I have Samsung Galaxy S4 and Using Android 4.2.2 in emulator with 1500 mb ram and ARM CPU configuration

Comment: just wondering, why don't you simply use support-v7's `DrawerLayout`?

Comment: I want to use two different layouts calling with two different button and both are showing with help of MenuDrawer

Comment: i believe the same can be done in `DrawerLayout` too

Comment: Can you please post a sample code ? I want two buttons over Drawer and different layout on each button.